# How do I propose a transaction with safe-eth-py?

Tags: python, gnosis-safe

I am working with the safe-eth-py package to script safe transactions. So far, I have only been able to execute transactions when the safe is set to accept a single signer. How can I propose a transaction such that I can do 2/3 signatures such as the steps described for Safe API Kit?

Thus far, I am using build_multisig_tx() to create and sign a transaction from my desktop, but I would like to assume I do not have access to all private keys (i.e. another key on my phone). The execute() command reverts when I do not have all signers present, so I am aware I need to use some kind of propose_transaction() function, which I cannot find for python.